# Is $\max_{\|x\|_p=\|y\|_p=1} |\langle x, Ay\rangle|$ equivalent to $\max_{\|x\|_p=|} |\langle x, Ax\rangle|$ for symmetric $A$ & $p\geq 2$?

Tags: matrices, multilinear-algebra, tensor

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a symmetric matrix, and consider the $l_p$ norm ($p\geq 2$).
Can we prove that the following problems are equivalent:
$$\max_{\|x\|_p=\|y\|_p=1} \left| \langle x, Ay\rangle \right|$$
and 
$$\max_{\|x\|_p=1} \left| \langle x, Ax\rangle \right| $$

Can the result be generalized to symmetric tensor and symmetric multilinear form? In particular, if $F: R^n\times\cdots\times R^n$ is a $m$-order symmetric multilinear form, can we prove the problem
$$\max_{\|x_1\|_p=\cdots=\|x_m\|_p=1} \left| F(x_1,\ldots,x_m) \right|$$
is equivalent to
$$\max_{\|x\|_p=1} \left| F(x,\ldots,x) \right| $$
If not, can we prove if for any special case? (the case $p\neq 2$ would be more interesting.)

Thank you very much!

PS: I would even highly appreciate if someone could give me an example where the above statement fails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is false for every $p>2$. Take $A=\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$. Then the maximum of $|\vec{x}^T A \vec{x}|$ on $|x|_p=1$ is $1$, achieved on the coordinate axes. (The proof is an easy computation with Lagrange multipliers.) But the maximum of $\vec{x}^T A \vec{y}$ is $2^{1-2/p}$ (achieved at $(\sqrt[p]{1/2}, \sqrt[p]{1/2})$, $(\sqrt[p]{1/2}, - \sqrt[p]{1/2})$), which is greater for $p>2$. 
(Of course, the claim is true if $A$ is positive definite. By the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, if $A$ is positive definite, $|\vec{x}^T A \vec{y}| \leq \sqrt{(\vec{x}^T A \vec{x}) (\vec{y}^T A \vec{y})} \leq \max(\vec{x}^T A \vec{x}, \vec{y}^T A \vec{y})$, so $\max_{\vec{x}, \vec{y} \in S} |\vec{x}^T A \vec{y} | = \max_{\vec{z} \in S} \vec{z}^T A \vec{z}$ for any $S$ at all.)

For $p=2$ and $F$ of any degree, this is true and is a theorem of Banach: "[Über homogene Polynome in $(L^2)$](https://eudml.org/doc/218624)" Studia Mathematica (1938) Volume: 7, Issue: 1, page 36-44 . A proof in English can be found as Proposition $1.2^{\circ}$ in  [Polynomials and multilinear mappings in topological vector-spaces](https://eudml.org/doc/217555) Jacek Bochnak; Józef Siciak Studia Mathematica (1971) Volume: 39, Issue: 1, page 59-76

I learned all of this from "[Estimates for polynomial norms on $L_p(\mu)$ spaces](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100064185)", I. Sarantopoulos, Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society, Volume 99, Issue 02, March 1986, pp 263-271, which has much more to say about the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much David! So, the result does not hold in general. But the fact that it holds for psd $A$ is somehow interesting as you pointed out. Is there any generalization of this to tensors that you are aware of? If not, what could be the assumptions on the tensor that potentially make the statement become true? Any comment on this would be helpful and appreciated.